# Python: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python

## Building tensor

```
V_High  = np.array( [np.ones(N)] )
V_Low   = np.array( [np.ones(N)] )
V_Close = np.array( [np.ones(N)] )
for i in range(M-1):
    V_High = np.vstack((V_High, Database[i][t+Starting_index-N:t+Starting_index,1]))
    V_Low = np.vstack((V_Low, Database[i][t+Starting_index-N:t+Starting_index,2]))
    V_Close = np.vstack((V_Close, Database[i][t+Starting_index-N:t+Starting_index,3]))
x_t = np.stack( ( V_High, V_Low, V_Close), axis = 2 )
x_t = x_t.reshape( 1, M, N, Feature)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

`V_High = np.vstack((V_High, Database[i][t+Starting_index-N:t+Starting_index,1]))`

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

How should I fix this error?